# How to get currently running job's node name in jenkins using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have sample-job running on node "Windows-prod" node.
How can I get the node name using groovy script?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague. There are two ways to run groovy scripts..  Groovy plugin on Console which runs groovy (..../script)

The following is for listing node for job using groovy console

```
def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("createAndPublishSnapshot") 
def build = item.getLastBuild()

println build.isInProgress()
println build.getBuiltOn().getNodeName()
```

Comment: I am using scriptler plugin, created one script and using that script in jenkins job. I am able to get build status by using your code but build.getBuiltOn().getNodeName() is returning blank value.