# How to get a list of running jenkins builds via groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Is there a way to get a list of RUNNING builds in Jenkins via a System Groovy Script?
I tried looping through the busy executors, but from an executor object, I cannot get the build object:

```
def busyExecutors = Jenkins.instance.computers
                                .collect { 
                                  c -> c.executors.findAll { it.isBusy() }
                                }
                                .flatten() // reminder: transforms list(list(executor)) into list(executor)

busyExecutors.each { e -> 
  println('=====print out methods of executor object=======');
  println e.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique();

}
```

I can also target the JOB that I'm interested in like so:

```
def item = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("my_job");
println item.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique();
```

But then I will have to loop through 100s (if not more) builds and ask each build if they are running.

There has to be an easier/better way of getting a list of running builds.

There is a lot of information on how to do various things via System Groovy Scripts (some of which I wrote), but I cannot figure out how to get a list of running builds:

[How to get currently running job's node name in jenkins using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831720/how-to-get-currently-running-jobs-node-name-in-jenkins-using-groovy)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console

https://gist.github.com/dnozay/e7afcf7a7dd8f73a4e05

[How to make a Jenkins/Hudson job surveil some others jobs and decide whether to build or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777663/how-to-make-a-jenkins-hudson-job-surveil-some-others-jobs-and-decide-whether-to)

Comment: Realized I have the same problem. Also a gotcha is that looping through executors only includes the slaves, not the master.  PS, see my example below. To get the builds for a job you can use `_getRuns()`

Comment: Hint ```import jenkins.model.Jenkins``` at top of script.

Comment: I wrote an [an answer to this over on Devops.se](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/13405/26211) where I used Groovy script to walk the API to find the info. It's a bit ugly, but Jenkins' API doesn't tend to provide a lot of nice helper methods, so that's not too surprising.

Comment: Just to summary: The only way is iterate all objects and ask if the result is null (in progress)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a couple ways to do this without using the REST API or parsing XML:

```
runningBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.getResult().equals(null) }
```

This assumes that you have not deleted or modified the default "All" view in Jenkins.  Of course you can substitute a different view name if you know exactly which view your builds are going to be in.  Or you can try this approach:

```
runningBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getItems().collect { job->
  job.builds.findAll { it.getResult().equals(null) }
}.flatten()
```

Although this approach doesn't require a view name, it also has limitations. It won't descend into folders or Multibranch Pipelines or anything like that. You'll need to manually descend into folders or concoct some way of doing it automatically. For instance, here's a version that works for a Multibranch Pipeline:

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(multibranchPipelineProjectName).getItems().each { repository->
  repository.getItems().each { branch->
    branch.builds.each { build->
      if (build.getResult().equals(null)) {
        // do stuff here ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think there may be a more accurate method to use than `build.getResult().equals(null)` to determine if a build is running or not, but I'm having trouble finding good API docs, so I'm not sure.  This was just the first method that I found using object introspection that worked. (Edit: Casirati in the comments below found what appears to be a better method: `branch.isBuilding()`.  This should work for both Pipeline and Freestyle jobs, but I haven't tested this method.)

Again due to the lack of API docs, I'm not sure if there's a significant difference between `Jenkins.instance.getItems()` which I used here and `Jenkins.instance.getAllItems()` which was used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44830061/1824868).

Finally, note that these are all relatively inefficient methods.  They iterate over every build of every job, so if you save a long history of builds (the default setting is to save a history of only 10 builds per job) or have thousands of jobs, this may take a while to run.  See [How do I Efficiently list **All** currently running jobs on Jenkins using Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988884/how-do-i-efficiently-list-all-currently-running-jobs-on-jenkins-using-groovy?noredirect=1&lq=1) for a question that asks how to do this task more efficiently.

Comment: That works! Wow! Thanks so much! I didn't know you do it that way!

Comment: what is an example of what you pass `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName()`? I just tried using my multibranch job name but it doesn't list the jobs. This didnt work `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('my-pipeline-job)`

Comment: @red888 If your multibranch project is named `my-project`, your repo is named `my-repo`, and you're trying to build the `master` branch, then the full name would be `my-project/my-repo/master`.

Comment: hmm i confirmed now I have the right path for the job but the snippet fails here: `repository.getItems()` with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getItems() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: The older Jenkins version returns null for Jenkins.instance.getView('All'). so instead of capital "All" use small "all" for older jenkins version Jenkins.instance.getView('all").

Comment: Yes thanks @DashrathMundkar .. i don´t know what you mean with "older" versions of Jenkins, but in my case  with Jenkins 2.289.2 .. this was the case!

Comment: @GedankenNebel for me on Jenkins version 2.176 it returns null but on version 2.235.2 works correct.

Comment: I found this works and doesn't rely on the result: "print(Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.isBuilding() })"

Comment: Thanks @Casirati, that does look like it fits the bill.  I added that one to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is not particularly efficient (but MUCH more efficient than using the API). It will print out all currently running builds with an HTML link. Can be run in script console or via scriptler.

```
def now = new Date()  // Get the current time
// Get a list of all running jobs
def buildingJobs = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).findAll { 
  it.isBuilding() }

buildingJobs.each { job->
    // Enumerate all runs
    allRuns = job._getRuns()
    allRuns.each { item ->
        // If NOT currently building... check the next build for this job
        if (!item.isBuilding()) return

        // Access and calculate time information for this build.
        def startedAt = new Date(item.getStartTimeInMillis())
        def duration_mins = ((now.getTime() - item.getStartTimeInMillis()) / 60000).intValue()

        estDurationMins = (item.getEstimatedDuration() / 60000).intValue()
        String jobname = item.getUrl()
        jobname = jobname.replaceAll('job/', '')  // Strip redundant folder info.

        println "${duration_mins.toString().padLeft(5)}/" +
            "${estDurationMins.toString().padLeft(4)}  - " +
            "<a href=${baseURL}${item.getUrl()}>${jobname}</a>"
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988884/how-do-i-efficiently-list-all-currently-running-jobs-on-jenkins-using-groovy for a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the REST API to get the list of running builds. Using the follow url:

`http://myjenkins/jenkins/computer/api/xml?depth=1`

You will get the follow response which contains `<executor>` elements. Only **running builds** has a `<url>` element inside `<executor>`. Note also that **running builds** has `<idle>false</idle>` value:

```
<computerSet>
    <busyExecutors>1</busyExecutors>
    <computer>
        ...
        <executor>
            <idle>true</idle>
            <likelyStuck>false</likelyStuck>
            <number>0</number>
            <progress>-1</progress>
        </executor>
        <executor>
            <currentExecutable>
                <number>328</number>
                <!-- This is the url from the current running build -->
                <url>http://myJenkins/jenkins/job/someJob/328/</url>             
            </currentExecutable>
            <currentWorkUnit/>
            <idle>false</idle>
            <likelyStuck>false</likelyStuck>
            <number>1</number>
            <progress>24</progress>
        </executor>
        ...
    </computer> 
<computerSet>
```

Hence use the REST API with an *XPath* for `url` to get only the running builds (note that `&wrapper` parameter is the name of the root xml element to avoid errors when the *XPath* not match or returns more than one node):

```
http://myJenkins/jenkins/computer/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=//url&wrapper=builds
```

You'll get something like:

```
<builds>
    <url>
http://myJenkins/jenkins/job/someJob/300/
    </url>
    <url>
http://myJenkins/jenkins/job/another/332/
    </url>
</builds>
```

So in *Groovy* you can GET the REST API, parse the returned Xml and then apply a regex to each `<url>` to get the data from running builds:

```
// get the xml from the rest api
def builds = 'http://myJenkins/jenkins/computer/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=//url&wrapper=builds'.toURL().text
// parse the xml result
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(builds)
// for each url get the job name
def jobNames = xml.url.collect{ url ->
    // regex to get the jobName and a build number
    def group = (url =~ /.*\/job\/([^\/]+)\/(\d+)/)
    println group[0] // [http://myJenkins/jenkins/job/someJob/300, someJob, 300]
    def jobName = group[0][1]
    return jobName
    // to get the build number
    // def buildNr = group[0][2]
}
println jobNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick command to get a quick view of all builds, queued and in progress.

`curl 'https://jenkins.example.com/computer/api/json?depth=1' | jq . | grep url | sort -h`

Answer (score 0):

> but from an executor object, I cannot get the build object

In 2023, at least with `Jenkins 2.341`, you can.

From your [Executor](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Executor.html) object you do `.getCurrentExecutable()` - this will yield [Queue.Executable](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.Executable.html) which will be something from entrails of your [Run](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Run.html) object, like `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.ExecutorStepExecution$PlaceholderTask$PlaceholderExecutable` for pipelines.

From it, in turn, you do `.getParentExecutable()` - it will be an `Executable` too, but now this should be an actually useful object of your `Run` subclass, like [WorkflowRun](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowRun.html).

So the resulting snipet should look like this:

```
Jenkins.instance.computers
    .collect { it.getExecutors() }
    .flatten()
    .findAll { it.isBusy() }
    .collect { it.getCurrentExecutable() }
    .collect { it.getParentExecutable() }
```

---

As a bonus, this is what I have in my groovy spellbook to list anomalously long builds (using `*.` instead of `.collect{}` and `.foo` instead of `.getFoo()`):

```
final HOURS = 2

final _hours_ago = java.util.Date.from(java.time.Instant.now().minusSeconds(HOURS * 3600))

println "Current time: ${new java.util.Date()}"
println "${HOURS} hours ago was ${_hours_ago}\n"

Jenkins.instance.computers
    *.executors
    .flatten()
    .findAll { it.busy }
    *.currentExecutable
    *.parentExecutable
    .findAll { it.time.before(_hours_ago) }
    .each { println "${it}\tstarted at ${it.time}" }
null
```