# How to list previous 24 hours job in Jenkins?

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins

How to list previous 24 hours job in Jenkins with the help of (Shell Script)?

Comment: Do you mean jenkins build ran in last 24 hours ?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307037/how-to-get-a-list-of-running-jenkins-builds-via-groovy-script